# Weird Color Overlay in Solid Shading Mode in the Viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

When I am displaying my mesh with solid shading in the viewport it looks wrong:

[image]

It has some weird blue overlay when it should have colors that look more similar to the ones I have in "texture" viewport shading mode:

[image]

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I can upload the file if necessary.
[This is my file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByTN_g1DxQR5bFVrSDh0OTBZWlk)

Comment: Is perhaps the normal map wrongly influencing the material color?

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering about that. I made sure that "Color" is unchecked in the textures tab under "Influence" for the normal map. Is there something other way the normal map might influence color?

I've edited the post to include a link to my file if you need it.

Comment: You didn't pack your images, it is impossible to diagnose texture related issues. You have a slightly bluish specular color, could that be it?

Comment: My mistake, I updated the link with my images packed. I checked the specular hue and that was not causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what is causing it, probably a visual glitch.

Whatever it is, its produced by a vertex color layer named "Col" your object has, removing it makes it display properly.

It is only present in *Multitexture* viewport shading mode, if you switch to *GLSL* the blue tint is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help you. Go to the shader editor, and just click on the diffuse texture image note. It seems like, that the solid mode shows always the last highlighted Image Texture, no matter if it is a normal map, displace or diffuse map.

Best regards